# PHP Zend creating form based on a database table automatically

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-form

Is it possible with the PHP Zend framework to create html forms based on a database table just with few commands? I am thinking something like that:

```
createForm("myTableName");
```

the command above would then create a html form based on the properties of the db table `"myTableName"`. i.e. a `varchar field(200)` would create a textfield with a `maxlength 200`. Or a boolean field would create 2 radio buttons automatically.

Comment: Both? I ve never used ZF before and i am trying to figure out which framework helps best to solve my issues.

Comment: Well I can tell for ZF2. Their are no code-generation in core ZF2. You need to search out ZF2 modules. I did not checkout but See this module help you https://github.com/enlitepro/zf2-scaffold .